# R ggplot2 is there are equivalent to the chart.Correlation function in the Performance Analytics package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]For several years I've been using the (excellent) chart.correlation function in PerformanceAnalytics to prepare summary plots for multivariate data. However, it does not seem to have options for using weighted data (which I always tend to have to deal with). I'm beginning to learn ggplot2 syntax as it seems to have the option for data weighting in most functions. I wondering if there is a ggplot2 equivalent to chart.correlation (see image below) or would I have to build my own?  Example code from PerformanceAnalytics below, which quickly produces a very data and interpretation-rich plot.

```
data(managers)
chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch="+")
```

Comment: `ggplot2` is very powerful and flexible and with right amount of knowledge it can be used to produce many types of plots. I am not aware of `PerformanceAnalytics` package but if you show your desired output that you want to achieve with `ggplot2` I am sure there will be a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use `ggplot2` functionality, you can use the `GGally::ggpairs` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

ggpairs(data.table(PerformanceAnalytics::managers)[,1:8])
```

You can define functions for the lower, diagonal, and upper plots. Here is simple example, where I define a function for the lower plots that is a simple `ggplot` with `geom_point` and `geom_smooth`

```
lower_plots <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_point(color = "black") +
    geom_smooth(method="gam",...)
}  
ggpairs(
  data.table(PerformanceAnalytics::managers)[,1:8],
  diag = list(continuous = wrap("barDiag", bins=50)),
  lower = list(continuous = wrap(lower_plots, color="red", se=F))
)
```

If you had a vector of weights (`wts`), you could customize your correlation in the upper panels by constructing a custom function for upper:

```
upper_plots <- function(data,mapping, weights) {
  # extract x and y data from mapping
  x <- data[[rlang::get_expr(mapping[["x"]])]]
  y <- data[[rlang::get_expr(mapping[["y"]])]]
  # get weighted correlation
  res <- round(cov.wt(data.frame(x,y), wt=weights, cor=T)$cor[1,2],2)
  # plot weighted correlation as a label in a blank plot
  ggplot() + theme_void() + geom_text(aes(0,0,label=res))
}
```

then, within your `ggpairs` call, you would set upper to a wrapped version of that function

```
upper = list(continuous = wrap(upper_plots, weights = wts))
```

Comment: Nice ... just had to add the line library(data.table)!  Expect I now just need to do a bit of research on how to do with weighted variables (looking for data weighted histograms and correlations)

Comment: @Markm0705 if you have a small dataset with example weights, so that I can understand more easily what you actually want to do, I would be happy to try to assist

Comment: Thank you for your offer of help. Typically the information I encounter is weighted by support (area, length, mass, and so on).  If you run these four lines to add a weight column to the 'managers' dataset that would give a reasonable proxy in the data frame 'df'.
df <-( PerformanceAnalytics::managers)
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
Wts <- rnorm(length(df$HAM1), mean = 5, sd = 1)
df$Wts <- cbind(df, Wts)

Comment: @Markm0705 added an example of custom function for upper that gets the weighted correlation, and then call that function in `upper`